# Confused about dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, ninject

I have a unit of work class, which contains an ExpressionRepository. I want to replace it with an interface (IExpressionRepository) and bind it to ExpressionRepository with Ninject, but here's the problem: My ExpressionRepository expects a DbContext as a constructor parameter, but you can't define a constructor in an interface as far as I know, so I can't call this constructor without using the concrete implementation.

Here's the code as it stands now, without using an interface:

```
    private DbContext _dbContext;
    private ExpressionRepository _expressionRepository;

    public UnitOfWork(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public ExpressionRepository ExpressionRepository
    {
        get { return _expressionRepository ?? (_expressionRepository = new ExpressionRepository(_dbContext)); }
    }
```

My best guess is to add a method like 'void setDataSource(Object dataSource)' to my interface, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear but if the problem is that you can't set up the `DbContext` at the point at which you're setting up your DI container (and thus can't inject the `IExpressionRepository` directly), then the solution to this is to inject a factory instead:

```
public interface IExpressionRepositoryFactory
{
    IExpressionRepository Create(string someIdentifier);
}
```

Here, `someIdentifier` is whatever information you need to set up the `DbContext` (e.g. a connection string or, better still, some implementation-independent ID that you can *map* to a connection string inside the factory). You can omit the parameter entirely if you know you don't need it (e.g. you're just going to read a config file).

Then, you inject the *factory* into whatever class needs the repository and you can specify `someIdentifier` as appropriate.

Usually what you'd then do is pass (inject) your repository into the unit of work, so the UoW isn't directly dependent upon the `DbContext` and just uses "whatever mechanism the repository has," whether that be a `DbContext`, a `SqlClient` or some other ORM.

If you're comfortable with always having a `DbContext`, you could just do the following instead - but this will mean that any repository implementation will always have to back onto a `DbContext`:

```
IExpressionRepository Create(DbContext context);
```

This still decouples the `IExpressionRepository` itself from the `DbContext` class - just not the factory interface.

Answer (score 0):

Use method binding if you don't want to use the factory approach mention by @Ant P:

```
Bind<IExpressionRepository>().ToMethod(context => new ExpressionRepository(GetMyDbContext()));
```

Or you can use the normal binding where your `ExpressionRepository` class takes `DBContext` as a parameter in its constructor and bind your `DBContext`:

```
 Bind<DBContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
 Bind<IExpressionRepository>().To<ExpressionRepository>();
```

Check out this question, it has the same approach i guess :

[How to handle DBContext when using Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921883/how-to-handle-dbcontext-when-using-ninject)