# should a repository be injected through a constructor or wrapped in a using?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

When using entity framework, is it bad practice to inject the repository into a controller?

For example if I have a service:

```
public class DogService
{
    IMyDbContext _myDbContext;
    public DogService(IMyDbContext myDbContext)
    {
        _myDbContext = myDbContext;
    } 


    public void CreateDog(string name)
    {
        //create a dog using the myDbContext
    }
}
```

Would the above be bad practice since we are not explicitly disposing of the repository, and would it be better to do:

```
public void CreateDog(string name, IMyDbContext myDbContext)
{
     using(myDbContext)
     {
          //create a dog using the myDbContext
     }
}
```

the stucture of mydbcontext:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext, IMyDbContext {}
```

**How do I dispose of the myDbContext?**

Comment: You don't typically "inject" a context.  A context is created, used, and destroyed.  More commonly, a _repository_ or something else is injected that then _uses_ the context.

Comment: thank you very much ive updated the question

Comment: To answer the other question, whatever _creates_ the disposable object is typically responsible for _disposing_ of it.  When you inject it into another class it complicates things.

Comment: @DStanley does that mean that my connection is disposed of as long as the object that creates the repository is disposed?

Comment: Only if the object that creates it disposes of it in the `Dispose` method.

Comment: You could use a factory to create the context and then wrap the factory call in a `using` if you don't want your DI framework to handle this for you.

Comment: you could also pass the context in as a factory such as Func<IMyDbContext>... though you could just make your repository IDisposable and handle its lifetime from your IOC container.

Comment: _How_ do you inject it? Because that is where the answer will come from.

Answer (score 2):

> Main question - Will it be a good idea to inject the `DBcontext` using `Dependency Injection`, if Yes, then how does it get disposed

Yes it can be injected, if using `Ninject IOC`, following would help:

```
kernel.Bind<DBContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

check out the following [link](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2013/03/27/managing-entity-framework-dbcontext-lifetime-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx), it describes both the patterns and also provides details regarding how to create a single `DBcontext` per `HttpRequest`, no matter how many controllers get invoked in the process.

Another useful link, [How to handle DBContext when using Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921883/how-to-handle-dbcontext-when-using-ninject)

Comment: Not only with Ninject of course. Lifetime management becomes the responsibility of the DI container.

Comment: @HenkHolterman agreed Ideally that shall be the case but with so many DI frameworks floating around, I am little vary of a blanket claim, Popular one like Ninject I have used, so is 100 % sure

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can inject the repository interface when you use the repository pattern. I mean you can inject it using controller's constructor.

**Lifetime of a Repository :**

All repository instances are Transient. It means, they are instantiated per usage.Hence you don't need to worry about the dispose of the Context.

Here is an example : this is a repository pattern.you have to inject the Interface of the repository.On this example where it uses a service layer.But you can do it on your controller as well.

```
public class PersonAppService : IPersonAppService
{
    private readonly IRepository<Person> _personRepository;

    public PersonAppService(IRepository<Person> personRepository)
    {
        _personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    public void CreatePerson(CreatePersonInput input)
    {        
        person = new Person { Name = input.Name, EmailAddress = input.EmailAddress };
        _personRepository.Insert(person);
    }
}
```

You can read more about it here : [**Repositories**](http://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Repositories)

Comment: Please don't use `inline code` to highlight random programming-related terms. It doesn't make your posts more readable, on the contrary even. See also [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text).

Comment: @CodeCaster OK sure, Thanks.I think this is  the 2nd time where you have given this advice.I'll follow it here after :)

Answer (score -3):

You could let DogService implement IDisposable and call myDbContext.Dispose() from DogService's Dispose method.

Comment: Who will call that Dispose ?

Comment: @MrinalKamboj it would be called by creating an instance of DogService within a using block:

Comment: You have not understood the Dependency Injection and its working in that case, if feasible, OP would have done this long back